# Accidentally ran chmod -R 777 /?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, android-emulator

So I was going to type something else with `chmod` but I ended up typing `chmod -R 777 /` but the good thing is I ran this in an unrooted Samsung j7 prime so it had a read only file-system and running android 7 and after I ran it I immediately killed it with ^C and I read output which said permission denied for many files. I also ran chown the came same way like this for fun a few days ago. Everything runs fine I even rebooted but should I worry about a problem with my device?

Comment: From where did you execute the command?

Answer (score 0):

I'd worry a lot – because what you did is equivalent to opening all doors and windows in your house wide, and then go sleep. The entire world (figuratively spoken) now has access to everything the `chmod` managed to touch. Not having run it as root might mean damage is not that extensive – but it could still be enough for the one or other mishap.

To fix up what might have been broken, unfortunately the only safe way is a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) – as it's hard to say which files/directories have been changed and even harder what their previous "access levels" were.

Comment: It is just a hunch, but maybe the OP won't need a factory reset. Let's see if you can guess why.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Don't take those things lightly – even if you assume OP used a "low privileged user" to run the command, at least all data owned by that will be laid wide open (you think terminal app, I guess). And despite of "no root", remember that ADB has elevated permissions (if that `chmod` was eg. run via `adb shell`).

Comment: Good one. If the command was ran from a terminal emulator, only this app's data is messed up. If, on the other hand, the command was issued from `adb`, then…

Comment: Always be on the safe side, @DeathMaskSalesman – and always assume the worst (you know that guy named Murphy). One should think *before* running (potential) dangerous commands. And the OP wouldn't be the first one having messed up a system using `chmod -R 777` on the root folder. I've seen more than one such case on SE already. Besides, I wouldn't be *sure* only the terminal's data was messed up. One never knows what crazy setups some manufacturers/ROM-cooks established. I'd *assume* you're correct there, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Kudos for the safe side thing. My idea could work for Lineage, but for Sammy's TouchWiz? Not so sure.